Woocommerce analytics for revenue and order showing all zeroes
My woocommerce analytics is showing all zeros, for all periods of time.
This problem started recently within last week. I did not do any updates or add in any new plugins.
I have tried all these (but still not working):

update woocommerce to latest version
clear analytics cache
import historical data in settings


I created a staging environment to test it yesterday.
It has all the same plugins and theme activated. The revenue and order analytics data is showing up correctly with no zeros.
When i add a new order, it is reflected correctly in the analytics
What could be the problem?
P.S: in my main website, only the Revenue and Order analytics are showing all zeroes. The rest of the analytics are fine. Also, the old woocommerce report function can still show the revenue correctly.
